# Branching in javascript

Tags: javascript, interpretation

consider this code:

```
if (a) 
    doSomething(a)
else if (b)
    doSomething(b)
else
    doSomething(c)
```

I can eqvivalently rewrite this using the javascript logical operators to this:

```
(a && doSomething(a) || (!a && b && doSomething(b)) || (!a && !b && doSomething(c)))
```

I know it's not really readable, but will this somehow be optimizing the previous version ?

Because of the fact that operator `&&` and `||` return actual expression value, will there be less comparisons ?

Comment: A major factor you should consider is readability. I've been programming for many years and I had to think about what your expression would do. The if/else-if/else was obvious.

Comment: Code isn't just about micro-optimizations. You have to be able to read it, and other people who come after you have to be able to read it. Debugging would also be more difficult in a single line like this. There's also a good chance you'll miss a parenthesis, or some other simple mistake that would take a long time to troubleshoot.

Comment: Any JavaScript JIT compiler worth its salt will produce the same code from both the forms you posted.

Comment: Totally agree. For this reason I've always disliked the `bool operator command` as a means to perform actions.

Comment: @JoeEnos yeha I know, it's not the most readable code ever, but my question is about something different.

Comment: How would there be less comparisons? Seems like there is more in the second example.

Comment: what is `doSomething` returning?

Comment: @NinaScholz it doesn't matter here

Comment: @epascarello, common subexpression elimination will get rid of them anyway.

Comment: I would have to agree with @epascarello. Rather than checking `a` once, you are forced to check the value of `a` three times, and, additionally, the value of `a` has to be `not`-ed two times. Same issue applies to `b`. (Although, `b` is not affected by this issue as many times.) Of course, as Federic said, a good JavaScript JIT Compiler will fix this, but then you have written code that is highly unreadable, and you really have not gained anything in terms of performance.

Comment: Why not? `doSomething(a||b||c);`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: How many JS interpreters/compilers do common subexpression elimination? I haven't heard of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has pretty much been answered in the comments, but I wanted to expand on some of the comments and offer some additional insight.

As [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi) pointed out in the comments, a good JavaScript JIT Compiler will probably fix both samples of the code, and produce the exact same result. However, let's imagine that there is no JIT Compiler providing optimizations, and let's instead imagine that you just have an interpreter that is executing the commands sequentially.

In that case, in your first example (*using if-elseif-else*), you would have the following steps taking place (excuse the rough assembly pseudocode, but I think it illustrates the issue):

```
 1. CMP a, 0 // compare value of a to zero
 2. JZ 5 // If comparison is zero (a and 0 are equivalent), jump to the address of the else-if (starts on 5) instruction
 3. CALL doSomething(a) // Not how you would pass a parameter in assembly, but we'll skip over that stuff as it is irrelevant
 4. JMP 10 // Jump to end line. We do not need to do other evaluations.
 5. CMP b, 0 // Compare value of b to zero
 6. JZ 9 // If comparison is zero, jump to the else instruction (line 9)
 7. CALL doSomething(b)
 8. JMP 10 // Jump to end line. We do not need to do other evaluations.
 9. doSomething(c) // Else, we do something to C
 10. RET // Return/exit. We are finished.
```

On the other hand, let's look at the sequence for your second sample of code (the one that uses only boolean operations):

```
 1. CMP a, 0
 2. JZ 6 // Start of comparison #2
 3. CALL doSomething(a)
 4. CMP EAX, 0 // Let's assume the call to doSomething puts a result in EAX
 5. JNZ 23 // Jump to end if doSomething returned a "truthy" result. Line 23 is the function's return point
 6. NOT a // let's say this call puts the NOTed a in EDX register
 7. CMP EDX, 0
 8. JZ 14  // start of comparison #3
 9. CMP b, 0
 10. JZ 14 // start of comparison #3
 11. CALL doSomething(b)
 12. CMP EAX, 0
 13. JNZ 23 // Again, jumping to return if doSomething returned "truthy" value.
 14. NOT a
 15. CMP EDX, 0
 16. JZ 23
 17. NOT b
 18. CMP EDX, 0
 19. JZ 23
 20. CALL doSomething(c)
 21. CMP EAX, 0
 23. RET
```

I'm going to go ahead and say that the sample code #1 (using `if-elseif-else` branching) would probably be more efficient. Again, as mentioned in the comments on your question, a good JIT Compiler will probably optimize both code samples to equivalent states, but if you are solely utilizing an interpreter, without any kind of compiler to optimize the code, then the code in your second example will require more operations because there are more conditionals and variables to check.

**NOTE:** *The assembly here is by no means 100% accurate, and it is really pseudocode rather than proper assembly. I have simply included it to point out the difference in the number of operations that must be executed for each code sample.*

Answer (score 3):

I was curious enough to run both functions (simplified) through v8 disassembler (`d8 --print_code`).

First version:

```
--- Raw source ---
(a, b) {
    if (a) {
        return foo(a);
    } else if (b) {
        return bar(b);
    }
}


--- Code ---
source_position = 47
kind = FUNCTION
name = x
Instructions (size = 284)
 44 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x18]
 48 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; debug: statement 60
                            ;; debug: position 64
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 8)
 53 REX.W testq rax,rax
 56 jz 184  (0x235a8cb66518)
 62 REX.W movq rcx,0x1d21fad2d781    ;; object: 0x1d21fad2d781 <String[3]: foo>
 72 REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
 76 call 0x235a8cb368c0     ;; debug: statement 77
                            ;; debug: position 84
                            ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
 81 push rax
 82 REX.W movq r10,0x144d04104121    ;; object: 0x144d04104121 <undefined>
 92 push r10
 94 push [rbp+0x18]
 97 REX.W leaq rdx,[r12+r12*2]
101 REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
106 call 0x235a8cb15d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
111 REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
115 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
119 REX.W movq rbx,0x7ed0fc04b11    ;; object: 0x7ed0fc04b11 Cell for 6144
129 addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
133 jns 166  (0x235a8cb66506)
135 push rax
136 call InterruptCheck  (0x235a8cb3ac60)    ;; code: BUILTIN
141 pop rax
142 REX.W movq rbx,0x7ed0fc04b11    ;; object: 0x7ed0fc04b11 Cell for 6144
152 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
162 REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
166 REX.W movq rsp,rbp      ;; debug: statement 141
                            ;; js return
169 pop rbp
170 ret 0x18
173 int3
174 int3
175 int3
176 int3
177 int3
178 int3
179 jmp 266  (0x235a8cb6656a)
184 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x10]
188 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; debug: statement 103
                            ;; debug: position 107
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 24)
193 REX.W testq rax,rax
196 jz 266  (0x235a8cb6656a)
202 REX.W movq rcx,0x1d21fad2d7a1    ;; object: 0x1d21fad2d7a1 <String[3]: bar>
212 REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
216 call 0x235a8cb368c0     ;; debug: statement 120
                            ;; debug: position 127
                            ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
221 push rax
222 REX.W movq r10,0x144d04104121    ;; object: 0x144d04104121 <undefined>
232 push r10
234 push [rbp+0x10]
237 xorl rdx,rdx
239 REX.W leaq rdx,[rdx+r12*4]
243 REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
248 call 0x235a8cb15d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
253 REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
257 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
261 jmp 119  (0x235a8cb664d7)
266 REX.W movq rax,[r13-0x58]
270 jmp 119  (0x235a8cb664d7)
275 nop
```

"Optimized" version:

```
--- Raw source ---
(a, b) {
  return a && foo(a) || (!a && b && bar(b))
}

--- Code ---
source_position = 154
kind = FUNCTION
name = y
Instructions (size = 372)

 44 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x18]
 48 push rax
 49 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; debug: statement 165
                            ;; debug: position 172
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 13)
 54 REX.W testq rax,rax
 57 jnz 69  (0x235a8cb66705)
 63 pop rax
 64 jmp 130  (0x235a8cb66742)
 69 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
 73 d0000 REX.W movq rcx,0x1d21fad2d781    ;; object: 0x1d21fad2d781 <String[3]: foo>
 83 REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
 87 call 0x235a8cb368c0     ;; debug: position 177
                            ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
 92 push rax
 93 40000 REX.W movq r10,0x144d04104121    ;; object: 0x144d04104121 <undefined>
103 push r10
105 push [rbp+0x18]
108 REX.W leaq rdx,[r12+r12*2]
112 REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
117 call 0x235a8cb15d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
122 REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
126 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
130 push rax
131 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 9)
136 REX.W testq rax,rax
139 jz 151  (0x235a8cb66757)
145 pop rax
146 jmp 296  (0x235a8cb667e8)
151 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
155 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x18]
159 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; debug: position 189
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 35)
164 REX.W testq rax,rax
167 jnz 179  (0x235a8cb66773)
173 REX.W movq rax,[r13-0x40]
177 jmp 183  (0x235a8cb66777)
179 REX.W movq rax,[r13-0x38]
183 push rax
184 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 31)
189 REX.W testq rax,rax
192 jnz 204  (0x235a8cb6678c)
198 pop rax
199 jmp 212  (0x235a8cb66794)
204 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
208 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x10]
212 push rax
213 call 0x235a8cb18560     ;; debug: position 194
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 27)
218 REX.W testq rax,rax
221 jnz 233  (0x235a8cb667a9)
227 pop rax
228 jmp 296  (0x235a8cb667e8)
233 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
237 REX.W movq rcx,0x1d21fad2d7a1    ;; object: 0x1d21fad2d7a1 <String[3]: bar>
247 REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
251 call 0x235a8cb368c0     ;; debug: position 199
                            ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
256 push rax
257 REX.W movq r10,0x144d04104121    ;; object: 0x144d04104121 <undefined>
267 push r10
269 push [rbp+0x10]
272 xorl rdx,rdx
274 REX.W leaq rdx,[rdx+r12*4]
278 REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
283 call 0x235a8cb15d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
288 REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
292 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
296 REX.W movq rbx,0x7ed0fc04b31    ;; object: 0x7ed0fc04b31 Cell for 6144
306 addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
310 jns 343  (0x235a8cb66817)
312 push rax
313 call InterruptCheck  (0x235a8cb3ac60)    ;; code: BUILTIN
318 pop rax
319 REX.W movq rbx,0x7ed0fc04b31    ;; object: 0x7ed0fc04b31 Cell for 6144
329 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
339 REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
343 REX.W movq rsp,rbp      ;; debug: statement 207
                            ;; js return
```

Even if you don't read x86 assembler, it's obvious that the "optimized" version has actually *more* comparisons and *more* branching (look for `jmp`, `jz` etc).

So the answer to your question

> will this somehow be optimizing the previous version?

is **no**, at least in v8 (I guess other engines are not much different in this regard).

Here's the dis of `foo(a || b || c)`:

```
--- Raw source ---
(a, b, c) {
    return foo(a || b || c);
}


--- Code ---
source_position = 220
kind = FUNCTION
name = z
Instructions (size = 228)
 44 REX.W movq rcx,0x36f71e52d781    ;; object: 0x36f71e52d781 <String[3]: foo>
 54 REX.W movq rdx,[rsi+0x27]
 58 call 0x117d9bb368c0     ;; debug: statement 236
                            ;; debug: position 243
                            ;; code: contextual, LOAD_IC, UNINITIALIZED
 63 push rax
 64 REX.W movq r10,0xb18ce704121    ;; object: 0xb18ce704121 <undefined>
 74 push r10
 76 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x20]
 80 push rax
 81 call 0x117d9bb18560     ;; debug: position 247
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 19)
 86 REX.W testq rax,rax
 89 jz 101  (0x117d9bb66945)
 95 pop rax
 96 jmp 109  (0x117d9bb6694d)
101 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
105 REX.W movq rax,[rbp+0x18]
109 push rax
110 call 0x117d9bb18560     ;; debug: position 252
                            ;; code: TO_BOOLEAN_IC, UNINITIALIZED (id = 15)
115 REX.W testq rax,rax
118 jnz 131  (0x117d9bb66963)
124 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
128 push [rbp+0x10]
131 REX.W leaq rdx,[r12+r12*2]
135 REX.W movq rdi,[rsp+0x10]
140 call 0x117d9bb15d80     ;; code: CALL_IC, DEFAULT
145 REX.W movq rsi,[rbp-0x8]
149 REX.W addq rsp,0x8
153 REX.W movq rbx,0xdf65a404b41    ;; object: 0xdf65a404b41 Cell for 6144
163 addl [rbx+0xb],0xd1
167 jns 200  (0x117d9bb669a8)
169 push rax
170 call InterruptCheck  (0x117d9bb3ac60)    ;; code: BUILTIN
175 pop rax
176 REX.W movq rbx,0xdf65a404b41    ;; object: 0xdf65a404b41 Cell for 6144
186 REX.W movq r10,0x180000000000
196 REX.W movq [rbx+0x7],r10
200 REX.W movq rsp,rbp      ;; debug: statement 261
                            ;; js return
203 pop rbp
204 ret 0x20
207 int3
208 int3
209 int3
210 int3
211 int3
212 int3
213 REX.W movq rax,[r13-0x58]
217 jmp 153  (0x117d9bb66979)
222 nop
```

Comment: Oh, I hate you so much lol You beat me to posting an answer about the number of operations such a thing would take at the assembly level :p I am glad someone else was considering that, though, and +1 for the fact that you included the proper assembly in your answer.

Comment: Could you please do the same thing for the simple `doSomething(a || b || c);`?

Comment: Aw, I didn't realise it's not comparable to the other two versions which do call different functions for `a` and `b` and don't have a `c`. Other than that, it appears the generated code is quite similar to the first snippet.

Comment: @Bergi: do note however, that there are always _two_ jumps per boolean op `push rax - call TO_BOOLEAN - testq - jz - pop rax - jmp`, while `if` generates only one.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to think about more is readability. You need to find the line between optimisation (speed, memory usage etc) and readability.

More often than not, these types of optimisations will yield small results (micro-optimisations), but hinder the readability a lot.

Comment: I have no problems with readability, i don't usually write such code in production, I was just curious to understand some innerworkings of javascript

Comment: @ampawd, then your implementation of JS comes into play -- with a pure interpreter, there may be a (slight) difference in speed between the two forms, but, as I said above, with a JIT compiler the optimizer will abolish the syntactic differences between the two I believe. The resulting machine code will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate each evaluation part with a return of `true` or `1` like in this example. Then it ends the check if one of `a`, `b` or `c` is true.

```
a && (evaluate(a), 1) || b && (evaluate(b), 1) || evaluate(c)
```

An even shorter version works with an array, because arrays are truthy.

```
a && [evaluate(a)] || b && [evaluate(b)] || evaluate(c)
```

Comment: What is this `(evaluate(a), 1)` syntax?  Is that something new in ES6?

Comment: Yup, should be `(evaluate(a), true)`, don't you agree @Nina?

Comment: @mash, it's the use of the comma operator.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, any truthy value would fit.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah interesting, just never seen it used this way.  Creative.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into

```
 (a && doSomething(a) || (!a && b && doSomething(b)) || (!a && !b && doSomething(c)))
```

suggests it is unlikely to be optimal.

Take the case where `a` is true but `doSomething` returns a falsy value (0, false, undefined, null). In this case `a && doSomething(a)` is false making expression evaluation continue with `!a && b` which is immediately false (`a` is true makes `!a` false) which makes expression evaluation continue with 
`!a && !b` which is also false.

So for example, blind execution of the rewritten code could cause `a` to be tested three times where the code using `if` tests need only test `a` once.